VBA Function to receive a workbook and return a class array
I'm trying to create a function that receives a workbook, scans through the workbook to create an array of classes, and then return the array of classes.  This is for work to try and automate the creation of a shipping report
Each line in the workbook is something that shipped, and each line contains significant amounts of data.  Using a class helps break up the information in a neatly organized array.
The name of the class is called Shipped
Below is the relevant code from the main sub.
Dim rawData As Workbook
Dim ship() As New Shipped
Dim x as String

x = 'path to raw data file
Set rawData = Workbooks.Open(x)
ship = importRawData(rawData)


Below is the function
Function importRawData(rd As Workbook) As Variant

Dim lineShipped() As New Shipped
Dim lastRow As Long

'code to find the last row in rd workbook and assign to lastRow

ReDim lineShipped(lastRow)
'loops and if statments to fill class array lineShipped()

importRawData = lineShipped()
End Function


I receive a ByRef argument type mismatch, and if I comment out the ship = importRawData(rawData) line, that error goes away, so I'm assuming I screwed something up in my code as I had this part working yesterday, but now I can't seem to get rid of this error.  I feel like I'm missing () somewhere or something silly, but I don't see it.
I've tried adding ByRef in the function, (), and changing the function to return Shipped() instead of Variant, but it all gives me a byref error.

I fixed it, but I don't know why it works now.  The error was in my Dim statements.  If anyone could explain how this change fixed it, I would be intrigued to know why.
This is what I had in my Dims
Dim thisWb, rawDataShipped, rawDataPending As Workbook

This is what fixed it
Dim thisWb, rawDataShipped As Workbook
Dim rawDataPending As Workbook

by putting the third workbook declaration on a separate line, I no longer get the byref error.
can we not put three variable declarations on the same line?

You need Dim thisWb As Workbook, rawDataShipped As Workbook, rawDataPending As Workbook

...in VBA every variable needs a type assigned, otherwise you get a Variant
